# CancellationToken not working in Asp.Net Web Api 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to add a cancellation token to my web api async controller in order to detect when the httpClient times out (so I can stop any pending await calls), spending hours on that without success. Here is my desktop app (.Net 4.0) calling the web api:

```
public void GetServObjAsync()
{
   try
   {
      var client = new HttpClient()
      {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000)
      };
      var myUri = new Uri("http://mysWebApi.net/myController");
      client.GetAsync(myUri ).ContinueWith(t =>
      {
         if (t.IsCompleted)
         {
            t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<servObj>().ContinueWith(t2 =>
            {
               if (!t2.IsFaulted)
               {
                  OnSerVObjReady(t2.Result);
               }
             }
          }
       }
    }
    catch
    {
       // Handle and notify
    }
}
```

Here is my web api controller:

```
public class ServController : ApiController
{
  public async Task<servObj> Get(CancellationToken Token)
  {
     try
     {
       await Task.Delay(15000);
       var resp = await singleHttpCallAsync(Token);
       if (Token.IsCancellationRequested)
       {
          return null;
       }
       var respObj = await multipleHttpCallsAsync(Token);
       return respObj;
     }
     catch
     {
       return null;
     }
  }

  private Async Task<servObj> multipleHttpCallsAsync(CancellationToken token)
  {
    var respObjs = new List<detailObj>();
    var httpCalls = new Task<detailObj>[2];
    httpCalls[0] = singleHttpCall2Async(0, token);
    httpCalls[1] = singleHttpCall2Async(1, token);
    await Task.WhenAll(httpCalls);
    respObjs.Add(await httpCalls[0]);
    respObjs.Add(await httpCalls[1]);
    return new servObj(respObjs);
  }
}
```

I have tried the approach stated in [Client disconnects in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2014/06/27/ClientDisconnectsInASPNETWebAPI.aspx), an many others, played with different timeouts, but at the end, the request is complete and servObj(respObjs) is returned. Any help on why the httpClient.timeout is not reflected in my controller would be appreciated.